# Answer Lost on Migration

Tags: support, migration, deleted-answers

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13876/complex-sql-query-need-help) was migrated to DBA, but my answer got lost in the migration. What Gives?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [click back to Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136760/complex-sql-query-need-help?noredirect=1) from [the migrated question on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13876/complex-sql-query-need-help), you'll see your deleted answer and a comment explaining why it was deleted.

In this case, your answer was a commentary on the asker's choice of language and not a direct answer to the question, so it was deleted as part of the preparation of the question for migration to DBA.

The banner doesn't seem right, though. In a migration, deleted answers are not migrated with the question, so the banner is incorrect (and of course, a bad user experience).

Comment: did you read his question before deleting? It is "Can anyone suggest an approach that might complete in a reasonable timeframe?" I answered exactly that.. He did NOT ask for an SQL Answer.

Comment: @Morons I did, and had a DBA mod review the question before migration. The consensus was to delete your answer lest it be heavily down-voted on DBA.

Comment: Np, I put it back...

Comment: it will be interesting to see if it really gets down voted that much.